# Why my gulpfile do not compile my sass but everything else works great

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm gulp newbie, actually everything works great but not the sass compiler, like.. It doesn't work totally.

here is my github repo without node_modules but I hope that everything is in gulpfile.js and package.json;
https://github.com/DanielKlys7/portfolio

especially: 
https://github.com/DanielKlys7/portfolio/blob/master/gulpfile.js
https://github.com/DanielKlys7/portfolio/blob/master/package.json

I tried almost everything, mainly it was in scss but I change it to sass that I work in recently.

```
    function cssTask(done) {
        src(config.app.sass)
            .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
            }))
            .pipe(rename({
                suffix: '.bundle'
            }))
            .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
            .pipe(dest(config.dist.base))
        done();
}
```

I expect my gulp configuration to compile sass into /dist properly because now it does not compile totally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in some global installs with npm